# Normalize a contingency table

Tags: r, contingency

Suppose I have a table

```
> tab <- table(c("www.a.com","a.com","a.com","www.b.com"))
> tab
    a.com www.a.com www.b.com 
        2         1         1
```

I want to merge the entries for `"www.a.com"` and `"a.com"` to get

```
    a.com  b.com 
        3      1
```

I have

```
> fqdn.normalization.regexp <- "^ww*[0-9]*\\."
> normalize.fqdn <- function (domain) sub(fqdn.normalization.regexp,"",domain)
> normalize.fqdn(names(tab))
[1] "a.com" "a.com" "b.com"
```

The question is, how do I convert `tab` values to what I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
> names(tab) <- normalize.fqdn(names(tab))
> tapply(tab, names(tab), sum)
a.com b.com 
    3     1
```